# Searching data on multiple classes

Tags: javascript, jquery, dataset, getelementbyid

I'm trying to select all my div where data-info is false.

```
<div class="rows" data-info="false" id="test"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="false"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="false"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="false"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="true"></div>
```

I added an id for testing, and it works well :

```
var test = document.getElementById('test');
var dataFalse = test.dataset.info;
```

If I `console.log(dataFalse)`, I got `false`, and that's correct.

But I want searching using all my classes, not a single id if there is some data-info are false.

Trying the same with `getElementByClassName` don't works, I also tried to replace it with `$(".rows")` and other things, but still don't works and I'm wondering what I missed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
 $(document).ready(function () {
$("div[data-info=false]").html("false");
     });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="rows" data-info="false" id="test"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="false"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="false"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="false"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.getElementById` only looks for the first element that matches the `id`. After all, there should only be one element in a document with a given `id`.

Use **[`.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)** to use a CSS selector that returns a node list of all elements that match the selector. The **[CSS Attribute Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors)** is what you want here.

```js
var theDivs = document.querySelectorAll("[data-info=false]");
console.log("Matching div count: " + theDivs.length);

// Just for fun
[].slice.call(theDivs).forEach(function(div){
  console.log("Matching element:", div);
});
```

```html
<div class="rows" data-info="false" id="test"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="false"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="false"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="true"></div>
<div class="lite" data-info="false"></div>
<div class="rows" data-info="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To select where `data-info = false`, you can use an attribute selector:

```
$("[data-info=false]")
```

See [this link](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) for more

Answer (score -1):

The "right" answer depends on what you are going to be doing with the false elements.  If you are controlling their format (including "hidden") then the data-info= attributes should be changed to class= assignments.  It is OK to have more than one class for an HTML element.  If this is done, then the false elements can be found by using "GetElementByClassName('false')".

If you are doing something numeric with the elements found, then keeping the data-info= assignments would be considered proper, and those elements would be found by using one of the methods provided in the other answers.

Comment: This is not correct at all. First, it's `.getElementsByClassName`, not `.GetElementByClass` and this has limited use cases  as it returns a "live" node list. Additionally, the [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/data-*) attribute is designed exactly so that we don't have to add arbitrary classes (which is not the typical way to handle this)

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  I did not see adding a class for true or false was any more or less arbitrary than adding a data-info being true or false.  It seems to me that they are pretty much the same thing except there is no ."getElementByData-Info" to find the divs that are "classified" as true or false.  Could you point me to some information about the use of data-info, as I Googled it and did not find anything?  thanks

Comment: There is no attribute called data-info, per se. It’s the data-* attribute and I have already provided you a link to its documentation in my last comment. The reason we don’t just add a class is that it goes against the semantics of CSS. CSS is for presentation, not data storage.

Comment: I was able to find some informtion about data-, and although there seems to be a bit of polarization between 2 camps on the "Class" vs "Data-" question, there does seem to be a consensus that class is the appropriate attribute to use to control presentation.  So I guess it should come down to that, and since MeowMeow didn't really say what was going to be done for the "false" divs, we should ask for clarification and not make an assumption.

Comment: I don’t know what you are looking at, but there is no debate about class vs. data-*. And since the OP used data-, and for the right reasons (to store data), there’s nothing to ask about. Respectfully, this is not new. Separation of concerns is the way the web is coded.